# reading arrays in ini format with qsettings

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I have the next file, which with QSettings finds as iniFormat (QSettings::IniFormat).

```
[PortA]
pgmNames = { "C.pgm", "T.pgm" }
```

but how do I parse "pgmNames"?

Comment: it seems necessary to begin from `QStringList list = settings.value("PortA/pgmNames").toStringList();`

Comment: @VladimirBershov - the problem is that value() returns an empty string

Comment: Yes, empty string but not empty string list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Vladimir Bershov  said, I should use settings.value(param).toStringList().

Thanks Valdimir